# PostgreSQL - how do I create a window frame with a condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Let's say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_prices (
  stock TEXT NOT NULL,
  date  DATE NOT NULL,
  price REAL NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (stock, date)
);
```

I want to calculate for each day, the highest price for each stock in the preceding 3-month window.

I can't do a simple self join with `date - INTERVAL(3 'MONTH')` since my `stock_price` table has some "holes" for holidays and weekends. Similarly a naive window also does not work:

```
SELECT
  stock,
  date,  
  LAST_VALUE(price) OVER (PARTITION BY stock ORDER BY date ROWS 90 PRECEDING)
FROM stock_prices
```

I almost want a window frame here with a condition based on the current row. Is that possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: One solution is to generate the extra rows using `generate_series()`.

Comment: Non-problem: iIf there is a *hole* in the date range, that *hole* cannot contain the maximum price.

Comment: It has been discussed at dba.se: [Date range rolling sum using window functions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114403/57105). The question at dba.se uses SQL Server, but latest Postgres and latest SQL Server have the same set of features related to Window functions, so answers can be applied to Postgres with minimal changes. Both of them do not support `RANGE` window frame, which is important in this question. Either use subquery, or fill the holes in dates as @klin showed.

Answer (score 7):

You can fill up the table with the missing rows using the function `generate_series ()`, so a window function would return correct data. You can select the period of report specifying start and end dates in `generate_series ()`:

```
select
    stock, 
    date,
    price,
    max(price) over (partition by stock order by date rows 90 preceding)
from (
    select d::date as date, s.stock, sp.price
    from generate_series('2016-01-01'::date, '2016-07-28', '1d') g(d)
    cross join (
        select distinct stock
        from stock_prices
    ) s
    left join stock_prices sp on g.d = sp.date and s.stock = sp.stock
) s
order by 1, 2;
```

This alternative solution with a simple subquery:

```
select 
    stock, 
    date,
    price,
    (
        select max(price)
        from stock_prices sp2
        where sp2.stock = sp1.stock
        and sp2.date >= sp1.date- interval '90days' 
        and sp2.date <= sp1.date
    ) highest_price
from 
    stock_prices sp1
order by 1, 2;
```

will be much more expensive. In this case you should obligatory use the index

```
create index on stock_prices (stock, date);
```

Answer (score 1):

The generate_series option should work well,  although since months aren't always 30 days it won't always align to calendar months.

If you want to use an interval, you can also do a self join and aggregate. This will join each row onto all rows that meet the criteria (in this case I've set the interval at 1 week), and get the Max value within that result set:

```
select a.stock,
       a.date,
       a.price,
       max( b.price )
from   stock_prices as a
       left join
       stock_prices as b
       on a.stock = b.stock
       and b.date between (a.date - interval '7 days') and a.date
group by a.stock,
       a.date,
       a.price
order by a.stock,
        a.date
```

SQL fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bbec8/2